# The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'ELMAH_GetErrorsXml', database 'XXX', schema 'dbo'

Tags: sql-server, elmah

I'm trying to implement server logging for my SQL server and I can get to the error page using localhost. However, when moving to the server and attempting to access it on there I just receive the above exception.

I have added the role 'Public' to have the SELECT permission on the table but it still doesn't change anything. I even tried adding my UserID and Password to the connection string and I signed in to give it another go but I received the same error, can anybody help me?

The exception says I need to add execute permission to the role, however when I tried this, no execute permission existed.

Answer (score 2):

I had to add 'Public' to have execute permissions of the GetErrorXML stored procedure.

Comment: That's a bit of a hammer approach to a more delicate issue. It's much better to give permission to the actual user than everyone who is connecting to the server.

Comment: @DavidG I agree but I'm new to this stuff as the moment. I guess that I'll have to create a custom ASP role and use implement this on my users?